# Building a case statement in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I have two fields emailid1Status, emailid2Status. If emailid1status is true then i have to compare the given email with emailId1 column and same with emailid2Status. How to achieve this in Hibernate.

Below i have tried but no luck.

```
   from User where user.emailId = email OR user.emailid1 = select case when user.emailid1Status is 0 then null   else email OR user.emailid2 =  select case when user.emailid2Status is 0 then null else 
   user.emailid2 = email
   end
```

**UPDATE**
Getting correct result with below SQL Query. can any body tell me how to convert this to HQL or can it be possible with Criteria API

```
select * FROM user_profile a WHERE a.emailId = 'test@gmail.com' or a.emailId1 = (CASE WHEN a.emailId1_status THEN 'test@gmail.com' ELSE '' END) or a.emailId2 = (CASE WHEN a.emailId2_status THEN 'test@gmail.com' ELSE '' END)
```

Comment: Have you tried with criteria ?

Comment: @looser, can you please provide me a code. i have tried but dint get success.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention the case of email1Status1 & emailStatus2 are both true. By your above sql, assume [NVL2](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2049.htm) or [UNION](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp) is more appropriate.

Comment: they can be both True or any one can be True, i just need to put that in condition if it is true.

Comment: Yes NVL2 would work i hope, but how to achieve this in Hibernate.

Comment: Hibernate also provide native SQL, you can find in entityManage API. But your'd better check if your database support NVL2.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use HQL then the query will be:

```
session.createQuery("FROM User user "
          + "WHERE user.emailId = 'test@gmail.com' "
          + "or user.emailId1 = (CASE user.emailId1Status WHEN TRUE THEN 'test@gmail.com' ELSE '' END) "
          + "or user.emailId2 = (CASE user.emailId2Status WHEN TRUE THEN 'test@gmail.com' ELSE '' END)");
```